# How to find out if a method is deprecated?

Tags: php, manual, deprecation-warning

For example, I would like to find out if the function 
`mime_content_type` is deprecated.

In the [English manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), it seems not marked as deprecated. This is also true for all other languages, except in German, Chinese and Spanish - there it is marked as deprecated.

How can I find out which manual is correct? Can I find maybe a history of the manual? So that I can see if it was once marked as deprecated and then the note was removed again?

Comment: Where did you see deprecation mark in the languages? o_O

Comment: @u_mulder there is a red box. I only can speak German, so I am not so sure about Chinese and Spanish  - but in the German manual is (in german :D) a deprecated note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the immediate question - yes, the manual once had it marked deprecated and that was removed. The problem was reported in [bug #71367](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367) and fixed in January this year, though apparently not in all translations.

Note that this was a "soft" deprecation, meaning that an `E_DEPRECATED` runtime notice was not raised when the function was used - it was only mentioned in the manual.

---

To get a manual entry's history:

On each page underneath the "Change language" dropdown selector there is an "Edit" link:

[image: Edit link]

Follow it to open PHP's online docbook editor, where you'll be greeted with a login prompt. Click <kbd>Anonymous login</kbd> and it'll load up the editor for that page.

On the bar separating the panels click the <kbd>≫</kbd> expander:

[image: Tools expander]

And in the panel that opens hit the reload button in the "Log" tab:

[image: Load log]

which'll let you read the changelog and perform diffs between revisions:

[image: History]

Answer (score 0):

*If you include a function in PHP which is deprecated it will directly show an error while compiling that the function is deprecated.*

**There's no need to additionally implement a function in your code and make it more bulky else it will make your page load a little more slow as compared to normal loading time.**

Comment: But it depends on your PHP Version if its throws an error or not?

Comment: yes for example if you use the mysql_connect in PHP > v5 it will show an deprecated error for that you have to follow the updates procedures that have been defined :) like with php5 the OOP style is meant to be used instead of POP :)